# Return value larger than X with INDEX(MATCH)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please some help with the following:

In Excel, I have this table:

[image: Processors by GHz]

And I have this formula to lookup the combination of "Cores per host" and "GHz per host" that it satisfies the values of "Required cores per host" and "Required GHz per host"

```
=(INDEX(CPUData;MATCH(1;(CoresHost>C66)*(ghzHost>C36/C8);0);1))
```

Where CPUData is the table without headers, CoresHost and ghzHost are the defined names of the columns containing the values in the table above.

The formula is working, but the problem is that instead of returning the value larger than what is required, it's returning the value that is smaller.

For example, if the processor that matches the requirement or exactly exceeds it is the E52630, it will return the E52643 instead.

I have tried using -1 and 0, but any combination of those I've tried it gives me either an error or a completely wrong value.

How can I get it to return the processor that it exactly meets or exceeds the requirement?

Comment: Why are you referncing C66, C36, and C8?

Comment: You say "if the processor that matches the requirement or exactly exceeds it is". Based on this I think you need to change '>' to '>=' in both conditions.

Comment: Jacob, those C's are in the sheet where I have the formula, they are not referencing the table above.  Using ">=" yields the exact same result as without the "="

Comment: Then I would check that your CPUData array is defined as starting on the same row as both CoresHost and ghzHost. You have a blank row between the headers and data, and if CPUData starts a row earlier, it will give you the value from the row above what you want.

Comment: Would please tell us the values in cells `C66`, `C36` & `C8` so we can understand\validate the logic for the expected results and workout a solution.

Comment: Jacob, that was the issue!  So dumb of me...  Thank you very much!  And thanks EEM for answering as well :)

Comment: Say you want E >= 12 and F >= 33.6. What is the desired output? It can be both (16, 33.6) and (12, 40.8), which makes no sense. You should choose E or F as the first criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using an Excel Table (i.e. `ListObject`). If so, instead of using `Defined Names`, use the *"BuiltIn Names"* of the `ListObject`.

Try this formula instead:

```
=(INDEX(CPUData,MATCH(1,
(CPUData[Cores per Host]>C66)*(CPUData[GHz per host]>(C36/C8)),0),1))
```

Or this variation which limits the index to the `Processor` column instead of referencing the entire Table:

```
=(INDEX(CPUData[Processor],
MATCH(1,(CPUData[Cores per Host]>C66)*(CPUData[GHz per host]>(C36/C8)),0),1))
```

It returns `E52630E (2,2GHz, 10Cores)` with the following values: 
`C66` = 144; `C36` = 144 & `C8` = 5

This works regardless of the blank record at beginning of the table.

Comment: Thanks EEM! I'll try it out!